# One of a switch in a stack is frozen

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, stacking

I have a stack of 3750 switches, which have 5 switches in it. One of the switches (switch 4) in the stack is frozen. The way I can tell is because all the lights on the switch are turned on, and I cannot toggle using the mode button in the switch. Also, when I used the command:

```
#sh switch detail
Switch#  Role   Mac Address     Priority Version  State
----------------------------------------------------------
*1       Master xxxx.xxxx.xxxx     15     0       Ready
 2       Member xxxx.xxxx.xxxx     14     0       Ready
 3       Member xxxx.xxxx.xxxx     1      0       Ready
 4       Member 0000.0000.0000     0      0       Provisioned
 5       Member xxxx.xxxx.xxxx     1      0       Ready
```

The switch that is frozen is saying provisioned. How can I fix this? Can I just go ahead and reload this switch in the stack using #slot 4 reload? Can doing so effect any configs in the master switch?

Comment: If you have possibility than connect a console cable to the switch and check the CLI. I see a few times that the ios was corrupted on the flash and it can stuck at the boot phase.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a chance that resetting a single switch in the stack will affect the entire stack.  A worst case senario is the whole stack reboots.  So, plan for a stack outage and do the work afterhours if necessary.

Power cycle the frozen switch.

Answer (score 1):

If the switch is truly frozen, you will probably have to power it off and back on.

When the master thinks the switch is only provisioned, that means that it is provisioned in the configuration, but it cannot actually see the switch.

I doubt you can reload the frozen switch from the CLI.

Comment: Thanks Ron for your quick answer. So, I guess I will just pull the plug off from the frozen switch wait couple of second and plug it back on. And as you said that there is the existing provisioned configuration, when the frozen switch comes back online, the master switch will push the configs to the switch.

Comment: Yes. While you have it powered off, you should double-check/reseat the stack cables on the switch, and the switches to which it connects.